# SSRS display n/a when n/a

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, power-bi-report-server

I have dataset in Power BI which is displaying n/a in some fields. I have connected Power BI dataset with Power BI report builder and I need to handle n/a in report builder. So if the value is n/a I need to display n/a else I need to round off the value to 1 decimal places.

I have written an expression as follows:

```
=IIF(Fields!Year5.Value="n/a", Fields!Year5.Value, FormatNumber(Fields!Year5.Value,1))
```

For number value, I am able to round off the number  just fine but the "n/a" part is not showing as "n/a" but showing "#Error" when the report is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess it's having trouble with the equality condition due to a data type mismatch.

See if this works better:

```
=IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!Year5.Value), FormatNumber(Fields!Year5.Value,1), "n/a")
```